# How to grep any word that appears between 2 and 4 times?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

My file is:

```
ab  12ab 1cd uu 88 ab 33 33 1 1
ab cd uu  88 88  33 33 33 cw ab
```

And I need to extract the words and numbers that appears 2-4 times.- {2,4}
I've tried many regex lines and even regex101.
I cant really put my finger on what's not working.

this is the closest I've got so far:

```
egrep -o '[\w]{2,4}' A1
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Can you clarify *words and numbers that appears 2-4 times.- {2,4}*. Please add an expected output so that it would be useful for others looking at the question.

Comment: Does grep have the same backreferences as `sed`? In which case could use something like `.*? (\w) .*? &`.

Comment: Two to four times **per line** or **per file**?

Comment: the expected output should be uu 1 33 ab 88

Comment: @S.Gal : how can 33 be in our output? You said between 2 to 4? 33 occurs 5 times?

Comment: [edit] your question to at the very least include the expected output given that input as right now we're all guessing at what you might mean.

Answer (score 1):

Native `grep` doesn't supoort `\w` and `{}` notations. You have to use extended regular expressions.

Use

`-E` option as,

> -E, --extended-regexp
>                Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (i.e. force grep to behave as egrep).

Also use

`-w` to match words, so that it matches the entire words instead of partial.

> -w, --word-regexp
>                The expression is searched for as a word (as if surrounded by `[[:<:]]' and`[[:>:]]'; see re_format(7)).

---

**Example**

```
$ grep -Ewo "\w{2,4}" file
ab
12ab
1cd
uu
88
ab
33
33
ab
cd
uu
88
88
33
33
33
cw
```

---

**Note**

You can eliminated use of an un-necessary `cat` by providing `file` as input to `grep` instead.

Comment: Why does '12ab' appear in your output?  In the input '12ab' it doesn't appear 2-4 times as far as I can tell.

Comment: @dood `{2,4}` Is inclusive of the upper and lower bounds. I guess that is what op wants. If not op would have directly written `{3}` instead.

Comment: I get that, but the literal word '12ab' only appears once in the entire input, therefore why would it appear in the output?

Comment: @dood ohh, now even I am confused by what op meant by *hat appears 2-4 times* I guessed its about words which are 2 to 4 in length. Will add a comment so that op can clarify better.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP's question, or I do.

Comment: @Kent I have added a comment on the question. I think we need more clarity before answering further.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close; within character class notation `[]`, the special notation `\w` is being treated literally, put it out of `[]`:

```
egrep -o '\w{2,4}'
```

Also `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`, and you don't need the `cat` as `grep` takes file(s) as argument(s):

```
grep -Eo '\w{2,4}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use awk for it:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]++}
     END{for(x in a)if(a[x]>1&&a[x]<5)print x}' file
```

It will scan the whole file, find out the words with occurrence (**in the file**) in this range `[2,4]`

Output is:

```
uu
ab
88
1
```

Comment: OP needs to clarify, I made my solution as words in a line and you did yours as words in entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK, this solution counts the word instances per line not per file:

```
awk '{delete array; for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) array[$i]+=1; for(i in array) if(array[i] >= 2 && array[i] <= 4) printf "%s ", i; printf "\n" }' input.txt
```

Delete to clear the array for each new line. Use fields as hash for array indexes and increment it's value by one.  Print the index (field) with values between 2 and 4 inclusive.

Output:

```
ab 1 33 
ab 88 33
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl implementation for a file small enough to process its content as a single string:

```
$/ = undef;
$_ = <>;
@_ = /(\b\w+\b)/gs;

my %h; $h{$_}++ for @_;

for (keys %h) {
  print "$_\n" if $h{$_} >= 2 and $h{$_} <= 4;
}
```

Save it into a `script.pl` and run:

```
perl script.pl < file
```

Of course, you can pass the code via `-e` option as well: `perl -e 'the code' < file`.

*Input*

```
ab  12ab 1cd uu 88 ab 33 33 1 1
ab cd uu  88 88  33 33 33 cw ab
```

*Output*

```
88
uu
ab
1
```

There is no `33` in the output, since it occurs 5 times in the input.

---

The code reads the file in [slurp mode](https://perlmaven.com/slurp) into the default variable (`$_`), then collects all the *words* (`\w` with word boundaries around) into `@_` array. Then it counts the number of times each word occurred in the file and stores the result into `%h` hash. The final block prints only the items that occurred 2, 3, or 4 times, no more and no less.

---

Note, in Perl you should always `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in order to detect issues at early phase.